# Intersection of two Python lists based on condition

Tags: python, list

I want to make intersection of these two python lists:

```
list_1_begin = ["i", "love", "to", "eat", "fresh", "apples", "yeah", "eat", "fresh"]
list_2_find = ["eat", "fresh"]
```

And my expected result should look like this:

```
expected result = ["0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1"]
```

This can be done by two for loops, but what if I have first list of 10000 elements and second list of 100 elements, also the phrase can repeat multiple times. Is there any Pythonic way?

Important:

For example:

```
list_1_begin = ["i", "love", "to", "eat", "the", "fresh", "apples", "yeah", "eat", "fresh"]

list_2_find = ["eat", "fresh"]
```

Solution should look like this:

```
expected result = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1"]
```

So only if all elements from `list_2_find` are in the `list_1_begin` in exact order

Comment: Actually one loop with `in` condition is enough. You can write it as list comprehension if so desired.

Comment: Cheesy solution (works for "words" like in your example but not arbitrary strings that might include spaces or be the literal string `"1"`): `[w if w == '1' else '0' for w in " ".join(list_1_begin).replace(" ".join(list_2_find), " ".join(["1"]*len(list_2_find))).split()]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep it *pythonic* and efficient convert list_2_find to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) and use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_1_begin = ["i", "love", "to", "eat", "fresh", "apples", "yeah", "eat", "fresh"]
list_2_find = ["eat", "fresh"]

set_2_find = set(list_2_find)
result = [str(int(e in set_2_find)) for e in list_1_begin]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1']
```

As an alternative for formatting a bool as an int, one approach is to use an **f-string** as follows:

```
result = [f"{(e in set_2_find):d}" for e in list_1_begin]
```

**Output**

```
['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1']
```

Some additional info on **f-string** formatting can be found [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

**UPDATE**

If the matches must be sequential, use:

```
from itertools import chain

list_1_begin = ["i", "love", "to", "eat", "the", "fresh", "apples", "yeah", "eat", "fresh"]
list_2_find = ["eat", "fresh"]

len_1 = len(list_1_begin)
len_2 = len(list_2_find)

pos = chain.from_iterable([range(e, e + len_2) for e in range(len_1) if list_1_begin[e:e + len_2] == list_2_find])
positions_set = set(pos)

result = [f"{(i in positions_set):d}" for i in range(len_1)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
```

Comment: Your answer is amazing, but it should work only if all elements are are in the order. For example , with your solution it would identify "eat" even if word "fresh" is not next to it. I need it to identify both words.

Comment: How many strings (words) can the list_2_find have?

Comment: It can have from 1 to 10 elements, but in order for showing 1 in the result list, all elements must be in exact order. I have updated the question

Comment: @taga updated the answer

Comment: TNX, you are great! Can you just explain me this line: result = [f"{(i in positions_set):d}" for i in range(len_1)]

Comment: @taga positions_set have all the positions of the words found so basically i in positions_set is 1 if a match was found at that position